# How to use different guard when login in from web or api in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, restful-authentication, multi-model-database

I am creating a Laravel (5.7) application for a mobile app. So I have an API and a Web Panel, both need to log in and each have a model. For Web login I use the `User` model (since this are operative roles) and another model `Client` for the users registered through the app.

I am using `JWT` to create auth tokens for the mobile app and using the regular login for the Web Panel.

The complication is that the default auth.php `guard` is `web` and if I use the (following) authenticate method from the API it goes to look to the users table, instead of the clients table, and its fixed when I change de default guard to api **but the Web login then tries to look in the `clients` table**.

So, in short I've tried to switch this default guards in many different ways but it just won't work. Some of the tests (that failed) I did are:

- Changing the $guard variable in the login controller to web and setting api as default in auth.php
- Overwriting the defaults auth.php guard in execution time using `Config::set('auth.defaults.guard' , 'api');` or `config('auth.defaults.guard' , 'api');` (and all its variations) in my API's authenticate method

This is my auth.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients'
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'clients' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Client::class,
         ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

My authenticate method in my ApiClientController.php

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
//        config('auth.defaults.guard' , 'api'); // NOT WORKING!!
//        Config::set('auth.guards.web.provider', 'clients'); // NOT WORKING!!
//        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', Client::class); // NOT WORKING!!
//        config('auth.providers.users.model', Client::class); // NOT WORKING!!

        $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');

        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        Log::info("JWT Token: $token");

        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

Also, here is my Client model

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Client extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'phone_verification_code', 'phone_verified_at'
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

Comment: Try with `token` driver

Comment: Its still trying to look in the users table. "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'phone' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `phone` = 5517970659 limit 1)"

Comment: You can try https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport which is built for multiple auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$request` instance has a `user` method that takes one argument:

```
$request->user('apiguard');
```

If you are attempting authentication:

```
Auth::guard('apiguard')->attempt($credentials);
```

Comment: It works does log in but it does not generate the JWTAuth token, actually the variable $token returns true instead of the JWTAuth token.